# Using wood glue instead of fasteners for raised bed garden

Tags: adhesive, gardening

I need to rebuild my rotten raised bed. This time, I want to use 4"x4"x8' lumber to make a bed in 16' long and 12" tall. But I'm thinking to use Titebond 3 Ultimate wood glue instead of metal fasteners. The reason is fasteners put too much stress at one point but blue will distribute the stress to all surface.

But with Pacific NW weather on the west cascade, I don't know if TB III Ultimate will hold up or not since I haven't used it on any projects that constantly exposed to moisture.

Comment: Why is it so important to you to have such a secure connection in a simple raised bed? I've used Titebond 3 when I make glued up cutting boards, but never on a project constantly exposed to moisture, I don't think it would hold up. Why not just drill some holes and run some rebar to hold them in place? I might be missing something you are trying to accomplish, apologies if I am.   BTW, I'm also in the great Pacific NW!

Comment: Consider concrete. Wood rots, even pressure treated wood rots eventually (and can be dubious around food crops.) Concrete does not rot. https://manabouttools.com/super-simple-concrete-garden-boxes-part-1/ (not affiliated, did find instructive, even experiments with some lightweight concrete mixtures and dyes...)

Comment: I have an outdoor gate part glued up with TBIII, lasted about 2.5 years so far, but in the midwest.

Answer (score 2):

You're not building a deep space probe where you need to optimize everything as much as possible.

Screws and nails are plenty suited to the job. We've been building buildings with screws and nails for thousand of years.

If the wood is rotting, solve that problem. It won't matter what means of joining you use when everything is rotting anyway. Use good pressure treated lumber and good screws and your garden bed will hold up fine.

Titebond 3 or epoxy will work, but it will take much longer for no advantage whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think glue is good for framing in vegetable gardens. The glue could be toxic and bleed into the food.

I’d be careful of the type of pressure treated wood to use too. Some types are no longer allowed and could contaminate the food.